# iOS Developer Enterprise Program Distribution

Tags: ios

I am developing an app for my customer. They would be enrolling in 'iOS Developer Enterprise Program'

1. I can develop and test for them under their program and not pay $99 on my end?
2. When I finish the app for would I deploy it? I understand there needs to be some sort of server at the customer end. Does this server need to be a Mac? or can be windows? Could someone please explain

Answer (score 0):

First of all Enterprise membership is required when you intend to develop app for your internal purpose only. Or when you wanted to distribute your app to your customers without uploading to Apple app store.

Secondly , server side programming is done by the developer. So it may be MAC/Windows.

Let me know.

Comment: I don't think that is correct. Read the second last FAQ question on https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.php

Comment: Please explain a bit. I may be helpful.

Comment: Actually my company is developing an app for a customer. The customer would enroll into Enterprise program and add my company's development team. How does it work when we deploy the app. Does my customer need to have a windows server? Any particular requirements for this server? Do I still need to spend $99 on developers program your can I develop the app under customer's enterprise enrollment?

Comment: Thank you so much for he information.

Here goes:

1. Client (or your customer) enroll into entreprise program. Its $299 not $99. 
2. You create profiles and certificates and all the necessary stuffs you required using that program. And Of course not , you need not to spend another $99.
3. You develop, test the App. And deploy to the client or any number of customers without Publishing it to Apple app store.
4. No server needed.
5. You can directly share it using diawi or any other portal.

Comment: So where does the app sit? After deployment if the client wants to download the app onto his new IOS device. Where does he download that from? Is the app on Apple's server?

Comment: No. App is not on Apple's server.  <br>
1. You can deploy on www.diawi.com and share the link for testing purpose.
2. For final deployment, you can user your own server. Upload IPA file , set any security (if needed) .
3. User can download the App by clicking the link just like yours hyperlink. 

NOTE: You can customise deployment link by hyperlinking the IPA file path with some texts like "Download App here"  :)

Comment: If the customer decides to put it on his windows server, he can?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you can, you just need an invitation from the Team Agent, normally the owner of the account
2. Usually you deploy by a simple "OTA" (Over the air distribution) using a link, dropbox, but there are some web platform (such as [MobileIron](https://www.mobileiron.com/en))  that simplify the process of managing enterprise app distribution.